# What is the Time Complexity of Quick Union?

Tags: algorithm, quick-union

I'm taking the coursera course on Data Structures and Algorithms. The author mentions that Quick Find is O(N^2) which makes sense (given that N union operations on N objects might require N*N array accesses). However, I don't understand why Quick Union would be any better. It seems that in the worst case, one long narrow tree, N Find operations on N objects would also lead to O(N^2) yet the material says it's O(N).

So, one is quadratic time, and one is linear. I'm not sure that I understand why there is a difference. Example:

Quick find approach

```
int[] id = new int[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    id[i] = i;  

// Quick find approach

int QuickFind(int p)
{
    return id[p];
}

public void Union(int p, int q)
{
    int pId = find(p);
    int qId = find(q);

    if (pId == qId)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
    {
        if(id[i] == pId)
            id[i] = qId;
    }
}
```

Quick union approach

```
int Find(int p)
{
    while(p != id[p])
        p = id[p];

    return p;
}

void QuickUnion(int p, int q)
{
    int pRoot = Find(p);
    int qRoot = Find(q);

    if(pRoot == qRoot)
        return;

    id[pRoot] = qRoot;
}
```

Comment: Often in a union find datastructure, there'll be a rank stored in roots, and unions are performed by grafting the smaller rank root onto the higher one -- which prevents long narrow trees. Your question would be better if you provided a short extract of code demonstrating what you're talking about, and a specific case that you think is O(N^2). Then there's something concrete to answer.

Comment: Quick Union does in fact results in `O(N)` find operations. I think the textbook might be referring to a single find operation.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Naive implementation of find
int find(int parent[], int i)
{
    if (parent[i] == -1)
        return i;
    return find(parent, parent[i]);
}

// Naive implementation of union()
void Union(int parent[], int x, int y)
{
    int xset = find(parent, x);
    int yset = find(parent, y);
    parent[xset] = yset;
}
```

The above `union()` and `find()` are naive and the worst case time complexity is linear. The trees created to represent subsets can be skewed and can become like a linked list. Following is an example worst case scenario.

```
Let there be 4 elements 0, 1, 2, 3

Initially all elements are single element subsets.
0 1 2 3 

Do Union(0, 1)
   1   2   3  
  /
 0

Do Union(1, 2)
     2   3   
    /
   1
 /
0

Do Union(2, 3)
         3    
        /
      2
     /
   1
 /
0
```

The above operations can be optimized to `O(Log n)` in worst case. The idea is to always attach smaller depth tree under the root of the deeper tree. This technique is called ***union by rank***. The term rank is preferred instead of height because if path compression technique (I've discussed it below) is used, then rank is not always equal to height.

```
Let us see the above example with union by rank
Initially all elements are single element subsets.
0 1 2 3 

Do Union(0, 1)
   1   2   3  
  /
 0

Do Union(1, 2)
   1    3
 /  \
0    2

Do Union(2, 3)
    1    
 /  |  \
0   2   3
```

The second optimization to naive method is ***Path Compression***. The idea is to flatten the tree when `find()` is called. When `find()` is called for an element `x`, root of the tree is returned. The `find()` operation traverses up from `x` to find root. The idea of path compression is to make the found root as parent of `x` so that we don’t have to traverse all intermediate nodes again. If `x` is root of a subtree, then path (to root) from all nodes under `x` also compresses.

```
Let the subset {0, 1, .. 9} be represented as below and find() is called
for element 3.
              9
         /    |    \  
        4     5      6
     /     \        /  \
    0        3     7    8
            /  \
           1    2  

When find() is called for 3, we traverse up and find 9 as representative
of this subset. With path compression, we also make 3 as child of 9 so 
that when find() is called next time for 1, 2 or 3, the path to root is 
reduced.

               9
         /    /  \    \
        4    5    6     3 
     /           /  \   /  \
    0           7    8  1   2
```

The two techniques complement each other. The time complexity of each operations becomes even smaller than `O(logn)` ~ `O(n)`. In fact, amortized time complexity effectively becomes small constant.

I didn't post the code with above optimization because it's the assignment part I guess. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

I came across this as well. You are right, N `find` operations on N objects would also lead to O(N^2) for Quick-union. The main difference however is that with Quick-find, when performing a `union` operation you will always have to iterate through all the objects, this is true for the worst case and best case.

Whereas with Quick-union there there is no need to iterate through all objects, the union of two objects can be done in constant time.

Both approaches will have O(N^2) worst case. Quick-union might slightly be faster in certain scenarios depending on the nature of the input.

This is because with Quick-find, the union operation will always have a computational complexity greater than or equal to N. This is not the case for Quick-union, the `find` operation can perform computations less than N.

Answer (score 0):

I think
Quick-find does N union operations on N objects to find 1, but
Quick-Union does N find operations on N objects to union N
thus, the second is faster